# Converting spherical coordinates into Cartesian and then converting back into Cartesian isn't giving the desired output

Tags: python, geometry, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

I'm trying to write two functions for converting Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates and vice-versa. Here are the equations that I've used for the conversions (also could be found on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)):

[image]

And

[image]

Here is my `spherical_to_cartesian` function:

```py
def spherical_to_cartesian(theta, phi):
    x = math.cos(phi) * math.sin(theta)
    y = math.sin(phi) * math.sin(theta)
    z = math.cos(theta)
    return x, y, z
```

Here is my `cartesian_to_spherical` function:

```py
def cartesian_to_spherical(x, y, z):
    theta = math.atan2(math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2), z)
    phi = math.atan2(y, x) if x >= 0 else math.atan2(y, x) + math.pi
    return theta, phi
```

And, here is the driver code:

```py
>>> t, p = 27.500, 7.500
>>> x, y, z = spherical_to_cartesian(t, p)
>>> print(f"Cartesian coordinates:\tx={x}\ty={y}\tz={z}")
Cartesian coordinates:  x=0.24238129061573832   y=0.6558871334524494    z=-0.7148869687796651
>>> theta, phi = cartesian_to_spherical(x, y, z)
>>> print(f"Spherical coordinates:\ttheta={theta}\tphi={phi}")
Spherical coordinates:  theta=2.367258771281654 phi=1.2168146928204135
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting different values for ***theta*** and ***phi*** than my initial values (the output values aren't even close to the input values). Did I make a mistake in my code which I can't see?

Comment: What a wonderfully-asked question.

Comment: Just as an aside, check out this little feature: if you put `{theta=}` in your formatted string, it does the same thing as `theta={theta}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be giving your angles in degrees, while all trigonometric functions expect radians. Multiply degrees with `math.pi/180` to get radians, and multiply radians with `180/math.pi` to get degrees.

Comment: I remembered now that there are already two functions, `math.radians` and `math.degrees` which do the conversions, too. Looks a bit cleaner than multiplying by a constant.

Answer (score -1):

The results are correct, but you should check their value using the modulo pi operation.

Trigonometric functions in the `math` package expect the input angles in radians. This means that your angles are larger than `2*pi` and are equivalent to any other value obtained by adding or subtracting `2*pi` (which also represents a full rotation in radians).

In particular you have that:

```
>>> 27.5 % (2*math.pi)
2.367258771281655

>>> 7.500 % (2*math.pi)
1.2168146928204138
```

Comment: OP's inputs are clearly degrees, and not radians with multiple rotations. Also, if they were, the functions would still work just fine.

Comment: I just wanted to show that the conversions were working just fine.

Comment: Angle units are not mentioned in the question so I would not take assumption.

Comment: You're correct, but the degree/radian confusion seems probable enough to at least deserve a mention.